# Is it possible to prefetch full HTMLAudioElement using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio, amazon-s3, html5-audio

I did not find anything about that at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement).

According to the specification, I can only disable preloading with [preload](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#attr-media-preload) attribute.

Also, I tried syntax like `#t=[starttime][,endtime]`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Using_HTML5_audio_and_video) at the section **Specifying playback range**.

Server, in my case AWS S3, returns chunks of the audio with 206 http status code Partial Content.

[Example of the audio](https://ia902607.us.archive.org/31/items/tom_sawyer_librivox/TSawyer_03-04_twain.ogg).

Comment: You may need to integrate this S3 with lambda and API gateway with HTTP endpoint that receives starttime , endtime as params , and it responds with the playback range. Ok ? alright!